# Ubuntu and Arch dual boot - grub doesn't show Arch

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I’m trying to get a dual boot system set up with Ubuntu 20.04 and Arch.  I tried installing them both but I couldn’t get a grub menu to show both OSs and I need help.  It seems like everything I’ve read here refers to EFI and my computer doesn’t have EFI, although I used GPT.  Below is what I did.

I successfully installed the latest Arch on my new desktop, which does NOT have UEFI. 
In the install, I used fdisk to create 6 partitions as below after selecting GPT:

```
sda1 2M BIOS boot 
sda2 500M ext4 (for /boot) 
sda3 75GB ext4 (for Arch)
sda4 75GB ext4 (for Ubuntu) 
sda5 8GB SWAP 
sda6 rest of HD (for storage)
```

I then successfully installed Ubuntu 20.04.  During the installation I assigned `/` to sda4, `/boot` to sda2 and `swap` to sda5.

But when I rebooted, I didn’t get a grub screen, it just booted directly to Ubuntu.
I reinstalled Arch using only part of the procedure I had originally used.  I left the partition structure the same, but I reformatted the boot (sda2) and Arch (sda3) partitions.
I made the directories `/mnt`, `/mnt/boot`, `/mnt/ubuntu` and `/mnt/storage`.
I mounted sda3 to `/mnt`, sda2 to `/mnt/boot`, sda4 to `/mnt/ubuntu` and sda6 `/mnt/storage`.
I then followed the rest of the procedure as before, including installing os-prober.
The results of running os-prober and the mkconfig command were:

```
[root@ArchMesa ~]# os-prober
/dev/sda4:Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (20.04):Ubuntu:linux
[root@ArchMesa ~]# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux-lts.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot: initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot: initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Found Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (20.04) on /dev/sda4
done
[root@ArchMesa ~]#
```

But when I reboot, the grub menu only includes the Arch Linux installation.

I have started over by installing Arch on the computer as described about with the 6 partitions specified.  I then installed a desktop environment (XFCE) and stopped.  I still want to add Ubuntu to this computer as a dual boot with the existing Arch.  Actually, it doesn’t have to be with the EXISTING Arch.  I can start again from scratch, no problem.  Ultimately, what I want is a dual boot system with both Arch and Ubuntu 20.04, however I can get it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

Thanks, walttheboss.  From previous experience I was aware that the system will generally boot from grub installed by the last system.  I chose to install Arch first because I have read that the fact that Arch uses a generic name for the Kernel, whereas Ubuntu’s Kernel name includes the version, so each time it updates the kernel, the kernel’s name changes.  This causes a problem if the Arch grub does the booting, but the Ubuntu grub accounts for this.  (I may be explaining this wrong, but the idea that it is better to use the Ubuntu grub is what is important.)  That is why I chose to install Ubuntu last, so its grub would be the one the system booted from.  But it doesn’t show the Arch OS.

If I remember correctly (It’s been a few days and I’ve tried several alternatives.), when the system didn’t show the grub menu when I booted, the first thing I tried was using Gparted to mount the Arch partition (sda3) with the intention of then running mkconfig again, but Gparted wouldn’t let me mount the Arch partition.  I don’t know why.

Right now I just have Arch installed.  Tomorrow I will install Ubuntu again.  When I do that, I will choose to reformat the current /boot partition (sda2) and give it the mount point /boot.  I will also reformat the partition I made for Ubuntu (sda4) and give it the mount point / .  I’ll leave everything eles as it is.

If anyone has any comments or suggestions about how I should do this install so it will configure grub to show both the Ubuntu and Arch OSs, I’d be happy to have them.

Comment: So, you are using GPT with Legacy Boot mode instead of UEFI?

Comment: One quick thing comes to mind.  Have you run gparted and made sure the bootable flag is on for all partitions you want to boot?  So I think we need more details. The last thing you installed normally takes grub. That is it holds the details for grub. Have you tried running boot repair from a CD or USB? That might sort you out. Or force a boot into the Ubuntu.  Install grub on that partition. Then sudo update-grub.  Then reboot.  If it "owns" grub it may see the Arch install.

Comment: Yes, I'm using GPT with Legacy Boot mode instead of UEFI.

Comment: You only can have one boot flag per drive. And grub does not use a boot flag, but some BIOS/UEFI require one. Partition tools often use boot flag to set ESP - efi system partition for UEFI systems. Otherwise boot flag used by Windows in BIOS/MBR configuration for its boot partition. Are you attempting to share /boot? That normally does not work. Best not to even have a /boot for most desktop installs. Some server or if using LVM may need /boot partition.

Comment: I'm not using UEFI or Windows.  I don't think I'm trying to share the /boot partition.  It was my understanding that each new install would overwrite the boot partition and so the last install would be the only one on that partition, but os-prober would find and include other OSs in the grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grub-customizer`. Install it by running the following commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: It seems to be in the official Ubuntu repos now.